# Checking pathogen installation for vim

Tags: vim, pathogen

I'm new to Vim and am looking for a way to check if pathogen is installed correctly. Some sort of editor or command line command that would let me know that vim has access to pathogen. Thanks!

Comment: Install pathogen [correctly](Install pathogen correctly and you won't need to wonder if it's installed correctly.) and you won't need to wonder if it's installed correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type `:scriptnames` in vim.

Look for a line that says `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`. If you see it pathogen is installed properly.

---

If you have any line in your vimrc that looks like

```
call pathogen#infect()
```

And it doesn't error out when you load vim it is installed properly